# JavaFX.TitledPane with Button

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to add a `JavaFX.Button` on a Label of `TitledPane`?
[image]

Solution found!
Source: [javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=javafx:titledpane-with-checkbox](http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=javafx:titledpane-with-checkbox)

Comment: use google http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=javafx:titledpane-with-checkbox

Comment: @IEE1394, tryed to find "TitledPane with Button", have found nothing. Thanks, man

Comment: @IEE1394 Feel free to post quoted relevant parts as an answer (with pointing out the source). Otherwise we risk that question will become unanswered when linked content will change or link will break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane(); // or TitledPane(null,content)
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    Label titleOfTitledPane = new Label("SomeText");
    Button buttonClose = new Button("X");
    borderPane.setCenter(titleOfTitledPane);
    borderPane.setLeft(buttonClose);
    borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(40));
    titledPane.setGraphic(borderPane);
```